# Why is the punctual Hilbert scheme $S^{[r]}$ smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $S$ be an algebraic surface, and denote by $S^{[r]}$ the Hilbert scheme of zero-cycles of length $r$. Why is $S^{[r]}$ smooth? A standard result due to Grothendieck [1] for smoothness of a Hilbert scheme $\operatorname{Hilb}^P(X)$ in a point $[Y] \in \operatorname{Hilb}^P(X)$ is that
$$ H^1(Y, N_{Y/X}) = 0.$$
This is clearly true for all $0$-dimensional schemes, since sheaf cohomology vanishes above the dimension.

However, that criterion only applies if $Y$ is locally a complete intersection. But for example the triple point $$\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y] / (x^2, xy, y^2)) \subset \mathbb A^2$$ is not a locally complete intersection, so the criterion does not apply.

[1] Grothendieck, Seminaire Bourbaki n° 221, *TECHNIQUES DE CONSTRUCTION ET THEOREMES D'EXISTENCE EN GEOMETRIE ALGEBRIQUE
IV: LES SCHÉMAS DE HILBERT*

Comment: This is not trivial and very special for smooth surfaces (curves being trivial) and fails for all higher dimensions.

Comment: IIRC The tangent space dimension to $({\Bbb P}^m)^[n], m>1$ is given by young diagrams in that dimension $m$, corresponding to monomials, fixed points for the torus action. For $m=2$, the dimension by a "miracle" $({\Bbb P}^2)^[n]$ is smooth. For the higher dimensional young diagrams , there just are too many monomials, and, say,  $({\Bbb P}^3)^[n]$ becomes singular at most $n$-points that are "fat". It stands to reason that more general varieties don't stand a chance for dimension $m>2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness' sake, this was proven by Fogarty[1]. It goes in two big steps:

1. Show that $\operatorname{Hilb}^n(S)$ is connected.
2. Clearly, $\operatorname{Hilb}^n(S)$ has an irreducible component of dimension $2n$, which cointains all subschemes $Z \subset S$ which consist of $n$ distinct points. So it is sufficient to show that for each $Z$, the tangent space has dimension $\dim T_{[Z]} \leq 2n$, which boils down to a bit of commutative algebra.

I've only looked at step 2 up to now, but I think it is quite readable.

---

[1] Fogarty, 1968, *Algebraic Families on an Algebraic Surface*